# Multiple instances of continuous Webjob on single VM in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have a continuous Webjob running on my Azure Website. It is responsible for doing some work after retrieving items from a QueueTrigger. I am attempting to increase the rate in which the items are processed off the Queue. As I scale out my App Service Plan, the processing rate increases as expected.

My concern is that it seems wasteful to pay for additional VMs just to run additional instances of my Webjob. I am looking for options/best practices to run multiple instances of the same Webjob on a single server.

I've tried starting multiple JobHosts in individual threads within Main(), but either that doesn't work or I was doing something wrong... the Webjob would fail to run due to what looks like each thread trying to access 'WebJobSdk.marker'. My current solution is to publish my Webjob multiple times, each time modifying 'webJobName' slightly in 'webjob-publish-settings.json' so that the same project is considered a different Webjob at publish time. This works great so far, expect that it creates a lot of additional work each time I need to make any update.

Ultimately, I'm looking for some advice on what the recommended way of accomplishing this would be. Ideally, I would like to get the multiple instances running via code, and only have to publish once when I need to update the code.

Any thoughts out there?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the JobHostConfiguration.QueuesConfiguration.**BatchSize** and **NewBatchThreshold** settings to control the concurrency level of your queue processing. The latter NewBatchThreshold setting is new in the current in progress beta1 release. However, by enabling "prerelease" packages in your Nuget package manager, you'll see the new release if you'd like to try it. Raising the NewBatchThreshold setting increases the concurrency level - e.g. setting it to 100 means that once the number of currently running queue functions drops below 100, a new batch of messages will be fetched for concurrent processing.

The marker file bug was fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/commit/91da9ad2708d3f856a23db5ac46c37d6598ea09b) a while back, and again is part of the current in progress v1.1.0 release.

Comment: Thanks for alerting me to this new feature in the upcoming version. I had already been experimenting with BatchSize, and now with NewBatchThreshold. I seem to make small gains increasing the Threshold, and I see improvement in bursts, but sustained over a long time, having multiple instances of the webjob performs the best for me, so I'm still looking for the best approach to accomplish that.

Comment: @Gadget27 I'm kind of in the same situation as you.  What I did was increased the BatchSize to 32, and also duplicating the WebJob multiple times within the same server instance.  Basically replicating codes from MyWebJob to MyWebJob2, MyWebJob3, and MyWebJob4, then deploying all four webjobs to the single server instance.  Thus increasing the BatchSize to 4x32.

Comment: @staticmain I'm doing something similar, but I am not replicating code into  multiple separate webjob projects. Instead, I have a single webjob and I deploy it x number of times, each time modifying the webjob-publish-settings.json's "webJobName" parameters so the each publish event uses a unique name. (JobInstanceA, JobInstanceB, JobInstanceC, etc...). The end results should be the same, but coming from one project would make managing the code much easier I suspect.